# Is the javascript mvc pattern used?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller

The configuration of the folder:

```
-config
 -custom-express.js
-controllers
 -display.js
 -home.js
 -upload.js
-node modules
-views
 -css
 -display
  -files
   -Succeed
   -Temp
  -js
 -index.ejs
 -logo.svg
.gitattributes
index.js
package.json
package-lock.json
readme.md
```

I am studying node.js and analyzing the following source files.

How are they connected? Is the mvc pattern in use?
I'm confused. There is no definition of model.

Comment: have you looked inside the source files ?

Comment: Agree with @zython, it is difficult to say without looking  inside the source files. Although the folder structure is ready to accept the MVC pattern, nothing tells if it implemented or not.

Comment: How are they connected? How would we know?

Comment: MVC is a coding pattern, not a filesystem pattern. Folder organization has little if anything to do with it.

Comment: Without knowing the contents of the files, we can safely assume this structure represent the source code for Windows 10 - don't trust file extensions, those pesky developers write .js files and you always find Assembly language instead